# How to modify csproj PublishRunWebpack to include static files from external directory

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, webdeploy, asp-net-core-spa-services

I've started with ASP.NET Core Web Application -> Angular SPA, but I have moved the angular app to separate repository, outside the csproj.

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
frontend
  dist

backend
  wwwroot
  backend.csproj
```

Now I want to modify  the csproj so that the publish copies `frontend/dist/**/*.*` to `$(outputDirecory)/ClientApp/dist/**/*.*`

How should I modify the PublishRunWebpack target to copy those files:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>../Frontend</SpaRoot>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">


        <!-- THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED (I guess) -->
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem and after few hours I found solution for it. I guess that this is too late for you, but someone else may find it helpful.
As you said problem was with `RelativePath`. Default value "%(`DistFiles.Identity`)" use full filename and just append it to root publishing folder. Solution is to construct you own relative path as I did in code below.

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack"
          BeforeTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!--User app-->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)"
          Command="npm install"
          Condition="  !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') " />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)"
          Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <ClientDistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist/**/*.*"/>
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(ClientDistFiles->'%(FullPath)')"
                             Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>ClientApp\app\dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: I can't validate it right now, but it looks nice

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I found the frontend folder will not copy to the PubTmp\Out folder. That means the forentend spa application will not copy to publish folder.

I suggest you could try to create a new target to copy the forentend dist folder to the publish out folder.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```xml
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="CopyFileToOutput">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target  Name="CopyFileToOutput"  AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CopyItems Include="obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\PubTmp\Frontend\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)"
    DestinationFolder="obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\PubTmp\Out\Frontend\dist"
    />
  </Target>
```